# How to display django-cms in the admin of grappelli?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms

when I install django-cms in my project It does not work good because I have an install grappelli, I need know how to make it work grappelli and django-cms and that appears in the admin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it in the Grapelli Dashboard. In the dashboard.py file you have to reference the model that manages the pages.

some like this:

```
 modules.ModelList(
                    ('Django-CMS'),
                    collapsible=True,
                    css_classes=("grp-closed",),
                    models=( 'cms.models.pagemodel.Page',
                        ),
                ),
```

Greetings.